# Unity assign GameObject to a prefab which is instantiated at run time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script called "trigger.cs". This script is attached to an object in a prefab. The prefab is instantiated at run time.

Now this is what I want : [image]

And this is the game object that I want to assign without drag and drop.[image]

Additionally, if I could somehow hard code the "Death Menu" that would also be a solution.

Here is my trigger.cs file

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class trigger : MonoBehaviour {

public Text scoreText;
public Death deathMenu;

//the line below is commented because its not working for me and just throws an error. 
//public Death deathMenu = GameObject.Find("Death Menu");


void Start(){
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    }


void OnTriggerEnter (Collider othercollider){
    Debug.Log ("You Are Dead !");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not working because you need to initialize the `deathMenu` variable in a **function**. You can't use `GameObject.Find("Death Menu");` outside a function. Using it in a property is fine too. Any function is fine as long as the function gets called before the `deathMenu`  variable is used. The `Awake` or `Start` function are used for something like this.

Also, `GameObject.Find("Death Menu");` returns a GameObject not a script or component.  `Death deathMenu` should be `GameObject deathMenu`

This should do it:

```
public GameObject deathMenu;

void Start()
{
    deathMenu = GameObject.Find("Death Menu");
}
```

---

Now, if you actually have a `Death` script attached to your *"Death Menu"* GameObject and you want to access it, you need to use `GetComponent` to get the script after you find the  *"Death Menu"* GameObject.

```
public Death deathMenu;

void Start()
{
    deathMenu = GameObject.Find("Death Menu").GetComponent<Death>();
}
```

Comment: Ok...i,ve tried both of these....does,nt shows me any errors...but when i run the game it says "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: Let's focus on the first one for now. `deathMenu = GameObject.Find("Death Menu");` is causing `NullReferenceException`? Did you put it in the `Start` function? If yes, can you put it in the `Awake` function?

Comment: The first one is working fine...no errors nothing....but for some reason its still empty....and by empty i mean its like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/99cfl.png

Comment: I should have sent you the complete code....when the objects hits the collider i also run this line with..... void OnTriggerEnter (Collider othercollider){
  Debug.Log ("You Are Dead !");
  deathMenu.ToggleMenu ();


  }

Comment: Sorry  but I think you are lying. The first example in my answer cannot give you what you posted in your screenshot. Tell me exactly what's happening. You are trying the second example and telling me that the first one isn't doing anything....

Comment: The screenshot is for the second code sample not the first. The first code in my answer **cannot** look like that screenshot. Now, that I've said, you must attach `Death` script to the "Death Menu" GameObject if you want the second one to work.

Comment: "Now, that I've said, you must attach Death script to the "Death Menu" GameObject if you want the second one to work."..how can i do this via scripting...

Comment: You don't have to since "Death Menu" is not a prefab. Just do it from the Editor. If you don't want to then add this under my first code `deathMenu.AddComponent<Death>();`

Comment: you mean add this line inside the start function of trigger.cs ?

Comment: Ok so i added the line in the start function...no errors on compile but on play it gives an error that :" UnassignedReferenceException: The variable deathMenu of trigger has not been assigned.
You probably need to assign the deathMenu variable of the trigger script in the inspector."

Comment: The death Menu already has a script attached to it called "Death.cs"